# Server side datatable data ajax data load problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, server-side

I have a table with a lots of data in my live server database. In that case if I load the total data at a time it get 12-15 seconds which is awkward. So I need to load the table server side. I have done it via ssp.class.php . It going fine when I load the table as normal structure like below:

```
array( 'db' => 'tel1', 'dt' => 0 ),
array(
'db' => 'is_active',
'dt' => 1,
'formatter' => function( $d, $row) {
    if($d==0){
        $tr_color='no';
    }else{
        $tr_color='yes';
    }
    return $tr_color;
}
);
```

But I need to access a array which is define outside formatter function. I have tried to access it as global variable but it is not available formatter function. Also it is not passed as parameter. So how can I access outside variable inside formatter function:
I have tried like below:

```
array(
'db' => 'genere',
'dt' => 0,
'formatter' => function( $d, $row, $lang ) {
    $gender = '';
    if($d=='M'){
        $gender = $lang['maschio'];
    }else if($d=='F'){
        $gender = $lang['femmina'];
    }else if($d=='A'){
        $gender = $lang['azienda'];
    }
    return $gender;
}
```

The above code does not return anything. It returns blank in browser network. $lang is the array of outside array. How can I pass this array inside the formatter function. Sometime it is database connection also. May be I need to fetch some record from another table. SO this time I can not do the operation.

I have tried to fetch Datatable data from ajax as server side loading. But can not access outside array or variable which is defined outside formatter function.

Comment: Look into the `use` keyword, https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: can I call a function by use keyword? and how?

Comment: No, that's not what `use` does. You can use it to make variables from the outside scope available inside of a function, without passing them as function parameters.

Comment: Is there any way to call outside function inside 'use'??

Comment: If have no idea what you are talking about there. Have you not checked the examples in the manual yet, to see how it works?

Comment: Your function gets called by the datatables script, with _two_ parameters - so you can't add a third to your function, then the signatures won't match any more. So you need to pass your extra "parameter" into the function context via `use`: `'formatter' => function( $d, $row) use ($lang) { ... }`